# How to hide angular app when javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I achieve this functionality without using jQuery?

```
 ...

<noscript>
   <div style="left:0; right: 0; top: 40px; bottom: 0; position: absolute; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
    <span class="alert alert-info">This page requires JavaScript to be enabled to work.</span>
    </div>
</noscript>

...

<div id="application" style="display: none"  ng-controller="MyController" >
    ....Application HTML...
</div>

...

<script>
   $('#application').show()
</script>
```

Comment: you mean without javascript? or just jquery in particular

Comment: Preferrably using AngularJS style code, using directives or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide `application` div using plain CSS use style in

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        #application { display: none; }
    <style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

```
// $('#application').show()
document.getElementById('application').style.display = "block"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/C2V2J/